# C++ Program On Elementary Database Operations i.e. Record Management

Tags: c++, database, file, c++11, ifstream

When i execute the program and select option number 2 it reads the data from the file successfully but when i select the option number 2 for the second time , third time and so on... nothing comes up and it returns back to the menu.
I have tried so many times, same error comes every time. PLEASE HELP. Thanks to all in advance. love all.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//class for database functions
class group
{
private:
    struct person {
            char flag;
            char empcode[5];
            char name[10];
            int age;
            float sal;
    }p;
public:
    fstream file,t_file;
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    group();
    void addrec();
    void listrec();
    void modirec();
    void delrec();
    void recovrec();
};

//main function
int main()
{
    char choice;
    group g;
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"1.Add Records"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.List Records"<<endl;
        cout<<"3.Modify Records"<<endl;
        cout<<"4.Delete A Record"<<endl;
        cout<<"5.Recover Deleted Records"<<endl;
        cout<<"6.Exit"<<endl;
        cout<<"Your choice ?: ";
        cin>>choice;
        system("cls");
        switch(choice)
        {
            case '1':
                g.addrec();
                break;
            case '2':
                g.listrec();
                break;
            case '3':
                g.modirec();
                break;
            case '4':
                g.delrec();
                break;
            case '5':
                g.recovrec();
                break;
            case '6':
                exit(0);
        }
    } while(choice!=6);

    return 0;
}

//default constructor
group::group()
{
    file.open("EMP.DAT",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
    p.flag=' ';
    if(!file)
        cerr<<"Unable to open file";
}

//Add records at the end
void group::addrec()
{
    char ch;
    cout<<"Do You Want To Erase Previous Records ?: ";
    cin>>ch;
    if(ch=='y'||ch=='Y')
        remove("EMP.DAT");
    fout.open("EMP.DAT",ios::binary);
    fout.seekp(0L,ios::end);
    system("cls");
    do
    {
        cout<<"Enter Emp_Code, Name, age, Salary"<<endl;
        cin>>p.empcode>>p.name>>p.age>>p.sal;
        fout.write((char*)&p,sizeof(p));
        cout<<"Add another record ?: ";
        cin>>ch;
    } while(ch=='y'||ch=='Y');

    fout.close();
}

//list all the records
void group::listrec()
{
    int j=0;
    //position get pointer at beginning
    //fin.open("EMP.DAT",ios::binary);
    file.seekg(0L,ios::beg);
    while(file.read((char*)&p,sizeof(p)))
    {
        if(p.flag!='*')
        {
            cout<<"\nRecord N. "<<++j;
            cout<<"\nEmp Code: "<<p.empcode;
            cout<<"\nName: "<<p.name;
            cout<<"\nAge: "<<p.age;
            cout<<"\nSalary: "<<p.sal<<endl;
        }
    }
    cin.ignore();
    getchar();
}

//modifies a given record from file
void group::modirec()
{
    char code[5];
    int count=0;
    long int pos;
    cout<<"Enter Emp Code";
    cin>>code;
    file.open("EMP.DAT",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
    file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    //search an employee
    while(file.read((char*)&p,sizeof(p)))
    {
        //if record is found
        if(strcmp(p.empcode,code)==0&&p.flag==' ')
        {
            //recieve new data
            cout<<"Enter new Data: "<<endl;
            cout<<"Enter Emp_Code, Name, age, Salary"<<endl;
            cin>>p.empcode>>p.name>>p.age>>p.sal;
            //position put pointer to overwrite record
            pos=count*sizeof(p);
            file.seekp(pos,ios::beg);
            file.write((char*)&p,sizeof(p));
            file.close();
            cout<<endl<<"Press Any Key...";
            getchar();
            return;
        }
        count++;
    }
    file.close();
    cout<<endl<<"No Employee In File With Code: "<<code;
    cout<<endl<<"Press Any Key...";
    getchar();
}

//marks a record for deletion
void group::delrec()
{
    char code[5];
    long int pos;
    int count =0;
    cout<<"Enter Emp Code";
    cin>>code;
    file.open("EMP.DAT",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
    //position pointer at beginning
    file.seekg(0L,ios::beg);
    //search an employee
    while(file.read((char*)&p,sizeof(p)))
    {
        //if record is found
        if(strcmp(p.empcode,code)==0&&p.flag==' ')
        {
            p.flag='*';
            //position put pointer
            pos=count*sizeof(p);
            file.seekp(pos,ios::beg);
            file.write((char*)&p,sizeof(p));
            file.close();
            return ;
        }
        count++;
    }
    cout<<endl<<"No Employee In File With Code: "<<code;
    file.close();
    cout<<endl<<"Press Any Key...";
    getchar();
}

//unmarkmarks a record
void group::recovrec()
{
    char code[5];
    long int pos;
    int count =0;
    cout<<"Enter Emp Code";
    cin>>code;
    file.open("EMP.DAT",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
    //position pointer at beginning
    file.seekg(0L,ios::beg);
    //search an employee
    while(file.read((char*)&p,sizeof(p)))
    {
        //if record is found
        if(strcmp(p.empcode,code)==0&&p.flag=='*')
        {
            p.flag=' ';
            //position put pointer
            pos=count*sizeof(p);
            file.seekp(pos,ios::beg);
            file.write((char*)&p,sizeof(p));
            file.close();
            return ;
        }
        count++;
    }
    file.close();
    cout<<endl<<"No Employee In File With Code: "<<code;
    cout<<endl<<"Press Any Key...";
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: `while(choice!='6');`

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. In particular, remove the manual input, unless your problem is with the actual input operation.

Comment: thanks @Killzone Kid

Comment: Please add `file.clear()` to the beginning of your listrec method, as it could just be the eof flag that is not reset if you reach the end of file and  this will prevent further readings.

Comment: According to @Gabriella Giordano suggestion, file.clear() works but after closing while loop like this- file.clear();
system("pause");

Comment: I was just testing, and indeed it worked for me... maybe I was not clear enough, because you need to put it before the seek operation. Good it worked then. :)

Comment: Problem Solved.THANKS TO ALL PEOPLE. LOVE ALL